# How to make combobox function like if choose 1 then open panel1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Such as combobox text contain of 1, 2, 3 if choose 1 then open panel 1, if choose 2 open panel 2.

Comment: is any update? Please check if the following answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use if statement. Try to find out comboBox1_SelectedTextChanged event for more information.

Here pasted some of code for resolve your issue. Try it !

code-----------

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedText=="1")
        {
        panel1.Visible = true;
        panel2.Visible = false;
        panel3.Visible = false;
        `enter code here`}

    if (comboBox1.SelectedText=="2")
        {
        panel1.Visible = false;
        panel2.Visible = true;
        panel3.Visible = false;
        }
    
    if (comboBox1.SelectedText=="3")
        {
        panel1.Visible = false;
        panel2.Visible = false;
        panel3.Visible = true;
        }
```